# Wordpress - display author name and picture for pages/posts

Tags: wordpress, plugins, configuration

What plugin or configuration option is needed to display an author name and photo for pages/posts he/she creates?
I have several editors working on the website and I'd like to display the authorship.

Comment: Try this one [https://wordpress.org/plugins/birds-author-box/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/birds-author-box/)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using [get_the_author_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) - this will let you retrieve any specific field - e.g. `display_name` or `description` (this is the *Biographical Info* box.)

[get_the_author()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) will give you the name only.

WordPress doesn't support photos for authors/users out of the box, check the [plugin directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).